# Azure APIM import of WSDL

Tags: azure, soap, wsdl, azure-api-management

I'm attempting to import a wsdl into Azure APIM and getting an error that the wsdl file can't be parsed, and therefore I don't have a complete list of operations in APIM.  If I attempt to import via app service (SOAP APIs) I don't receive an error but the list provided is also not a complete list of operations.  When I upload the file I do receive a complete list of operations (without error) but then I am not provided any input parameters when attempting to test in the testing tab of APIM in the portal.  Importing the wsdl via a file appears to be most successful option of the 3 but still returns an error.  I've imported wsdl before and I don't recall running into this issue. Any idea why this is happening?

FYI... I can use the SOAPUI to test the SOAP api directly without using APIM.

Answer (score 2):

When importing an API, you might come across some restrictions or identify issues that need to be rectified before you can successfully perform the import.

For WSDL below are the points we need :

WSDL files are used to create SOAP pass-through and SOAP-to-REST APIs.

- SOAP bindings -Only SOAP bindings of style ”document” and “literal” encoding are supported. There is no support for “rpc” style or SOAP-Encoding.
- WSDL:Import - This attribute isn't supported. Customers should merge the imports into one document.
- Messages with multiple parts - These types of messages aren't supported.
- WCF wsHttpBinding - SOAP services created with Windows Communication Foundation should use basicHttpBinding - wsHttpBinding isn't supported.
- MTOM - Services using MTOM may work. Official support isn't offered at this time.
- Recursion - Types that are defined recursively (for example, refer to an array of themselves) are not supported by APIM.
- Multiple Namespaces - Multiple namespaces can be used in a schema, but only the target namespace can be used to define message parts. Namespaces other than the target, which are used to define other input or output elements, are not preserved. Although such a WSDL document can be imported, on export all message parts will have the target namespace of the WSDL.

For more info, follow this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions